# iis 8 website not opening

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have create new web site in **IIS 8**. I have configured my web site like this

```
http://ip:8080/
```

When I browse it from any public network it is not opening. But If I open is locally it works fine. `http://localhost:8080` it is working fine. What I tried I stop all other sites, `Default Web site` and assign `80` port to my site then it is working fine in locally as well as publically. I don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. I have opened a **8080** port on `Azure management portal`. And on **VM** I have create **new rule** which points to this port.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have a firewall or other network routing issue. Check all configured firewalls on your server/housing machine, as well as along your network path (router, or other perimeter network devices)

Also if trying to connect through your internet side IP you will want to check any port forward rules on your router (If behind NAT, like most connections are)

Comment: I have added new rule for 8080 port. But not worked.

Comment: Network setup and troubleshooting is not a simple task. Without prior information I can't help. It really sounds like you need to contact a qualified network administrator to assist you with your network configuration.

Comment: My problem is solved. I have opened a **8080** port on `Azure management portal`. And on VM I have create `new rule` which points to this port.